# How can I find and fix my android app's security vulnerability?

Tags: java, android, okhttp, trustmanager

I have received this message from Google. We aren't using any TrustManager or etc. We are using okhttp and google publisher, and I don't know how can I detect this security vulnerability.

[image]

> We found that your app contains security vulnerabilities, which can
> expose user information or damage a user’s device. This is a violation
> of Device and Network Abuse policy. Specifically, your app(s) are
> vulnerable to TrustManager. To address this issue, follow the steps in
> this Google Help Center article.
>
> Affected Version(s): APK: 21

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:8.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.8'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    implementation 'com.varunjohn1990.libraries:WhatsappMessengerView:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-androidpublisher:v3-rev20201125-1.31.0'
    implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.22.2'

    implementation 'com.github.drawers:SpinnerDatePicker:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.elyeproj.libraries:loaderviewlibrary:2.0.0'
    implementation 'link.fls:swipestack:0.3.0'

    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.4.0'
    // If you want to use the GPU Filters
    implementation 'jp.co.cyberagent.android:gpuimage:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation 'com.github.HamidrezaAmz:AndroidImageSlider:v1.0.8'
    implementation 'com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.6.3'

    implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0'

    implementation project(':bottomnavbar')
    implementation project(':segmentcontrol')
    implementation project(':scrool')
}
```

> \build.gradle: Error: commons-logging defines classes that conflict
> with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer
> versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem
> (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead),
> or repackaging the library using something like jarjar. [Dupli
> catePlatformClasses]
>
> \build.gradle: Error: httpclient defines classes that conflict with
> classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer
> versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem
> (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead),
> or repackaging the library using something like jarjar. [DuplicateP
> latformClasses]

This fixed those error:

```
implementation ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-androidpublisher:v3-rev20201125-1.31.0')  {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

implementation ('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.22.2')  {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

    OkHttpService service = new OkHttpService();
    SubscriptionPurchase purchase = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), 
            new HttpCredentialsAdapter(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(service.sendRequestInput(config.CREPATH + "credentials.json", null)).
            createScoped(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER))).setApplicationName(String.valueOf(R.string.app_name)).
            build().purchases().subscriptions().
            get(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, subscriptionID, token).execute();


<issue
    id="TrustAllX509TrustManager"
    severity="Warning"
    message="`checkServerTrusted` is empty, which could cause insecure network traffic due to trusting arbitrary TLS/SSL certificates presented by peers"
    category="Security"
    priority="6"
    summary="Insecure TLS/SSL trust manager"
    explanation="This check looks for X509TrustManager implementations whose `checkServerTrusted` or `checkClientTrusted` methods do nothing (thus trusting any certificate chain) which could result in insecure network traffic caused by trusting arbitrary TLS/SSL certificates presented by peers.">
    <location
        file="Project\com\google\api\client\util\SslUtils$1.class"/>
</issue>
```

Comment: Have you followed the steps in the Google Help Center article? Did you run lint before publishing? Maybe it will point you out the vulnerabilities.

Comment: @ChristianB It gives me this article; https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016 I don't have any TrustManager or X509TrustManager.

Comment: This might be related to your okhttp implementation. You should configure and run lint `./gradlew lintDebug` and check the results.

Comment: Please post your dependency list snippet for more clearity.

Comment: @MonimKaiser Added to post.

Comment: @ChristianB It gives me 2 errors. Added to post.

Comment: The error suggests you a solution. Have you tried this?

Comment: @ChristianB As I said, I am not using httpclient. You can check dependencies.

Comment: One of you dependencies or added projects is using httpclient. For that reason, you are getting this error. You have to find that and eliminate that one.

Comment: @MonimKaiser I detected them. They are google dependencies. (androidpublisher and oauth2) What should I do?

Comment: @MonimKaiser I fixed these codes on the post. Now it's not giving build failed error. How can I check security vulnurabilities?

Comment: Also check if your app is calling any **http** request. If not, you are free to go. I don't see any other issue.

Comment: If you found that androidpublisher and oauth2 are using TrustManager, you can search how to fix those inside this library ( issues tab in GitHub, or  just google "Fix TrustManager in xxx Library) , most of these libraries have a configurations for prevent this type of error.

Comment: @rguzman I didn't find any configuration. Can you check this; https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/issues/6792

Comment: @MonimKaiser I found some warnings about the vulnerability as I said. I am going to add the code. Can you check it too?